# Can You Benefit from Something To Which You are Indifferent Or Are Happy Not To Have

Tags: halacha, hanaah-benefit

Scenario:

Reuven is on a flight and the TV screens built into the seats are not working.  Reuven is happy because he doesn’t have to deal with the yetzer hara in front of him and he can learn Gemara instead.  He goes to the bathroom and overhears Shimon asking the flight attendant in the back if he can get a voucher for not having been able to use the TV. The flight attendant explains how to obtain one.  Reuven thinks to himself, “Why can’t I claim a voucher too,” since his TV was also not working.  However, not only did Reuven not care that his TV wasn’t working but he was happy.

Question:

Can Reuven benefit (i.e. Receive a voucher if the airline is willing to offer one) for having paid for use of the TV as part of the airfaire even though he didn’t care to use the TV or was happy it was not working?